# plm function dropping control variables only when not included with "ds$" before them

Tags: r, multicollinearity, plm

I noticed some interesting behaviour of the `plm` function (from package `plm`) in R today:

When running models such as:

```
did1<- plm(dependent ~ interaction + treatment + time + industry + year + log(assets) +  control1 + control2, data = ds, model = "within", index = c("id", "time"))
```

the plm function drops most of the included explanatory variables, such that only 3 are left. I am running quite a lot of models similar to this one with many different dependent variables, and it always drops the same ones and keeps the same three. When investigating with

```
detect.lindep(did1)
```

I found that all excluded variables are classified as "suspicious" (of linear dependence). Even though I was very surprised by it excluding this many, I guess it made the models better - almost all models have very high significance this way.

Now to my new discovery: When including the variables like this

```
did1<- plm(ds$dependent ~ ds$interaction + ds$treatment + ds$time + ds$industry + ds$year + log(ds$assets) +  ds$control1 + ds$control2, data = ds, model = "within", index = c("id", "time"))
```

none of them are dropped and all are included in the ouputs. I have not found models that have lower significance this way, however it seems weird to me that apparently all other variables are in some way multicolinear with the three included ones, as they have very different meanings, two are categorical and one is a dummy and one is an integer.

Lastly, when running the models the second way, the time variable is dropped in the output. Somehow, this made sense to me as I am running difference in differences models, yet it is included in the first type models.

Comment: Without a reproducible example (e.g., with a toy day set), this will be hard to answer.

Comment: Note, though, that for FE models, collinearity might arise after the FE transformation of the data, so somewhat unexpected when looking at the original data. See the help page `?plm::detect.lindep` for a toy example.